# Localizable.strings for each country/language

Tags: objective-c

I set up a test app with a localizable.strings file.  In the project settings i add English-United Kingdom, french, and french-france

The "french" strings file works in the app.  I see the localized version when i choose the language "france"

However, when i set language to English and Region Form to "United Kingdom", im expecting to see the string that comes from the en-GB strings file.  Im seeing the English version.  I'm obviously missing something here.  Same when i use "French - France".  i would expect it to use fr-FR version of the strings file.

I've got French-France, French-switzerland, etc.  How do i implement these?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is this ios (iPhone) ?, further please post the names of your string files and the location (Project root?)

Comment: iPhone doesn't read country-specific localized files, only OS X does that.

Comment: Yeh i just found that out >.<  why does XCode let me create them?  You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds.(click on this box to dismiss)Important: In iOS, the bundle interfaces do not take dialect or script information into account when looking for localized resources; only the language designator code is considered. Therefore if your project includes language-specific project directories with both a language and region designator, those directories are ignored. The bundle interfaces in Mac OS X do support region designators in language-specific project directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem that I solved by explicitly setting the localization directory from which to get the strings (my issue link and text below).

[iOS Localizable.strings not being retrieved from BASE file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25680874/ios-localizable-strings-not-being-retrieved-from-base-file/25927392#25927392)

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"];
if (path == nil)
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Base" ofType:@"lproj"];
}

NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"TAB_TITLE_Camera", @"Localizable", [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path], @"");
```

If you have a specific localization directory that you want to retrieve your strings from, you could replace

```
pathForResource:
```

with **en-GB**, **fr-FR**, or whatever other directory name you need.

I believe it's suppose to, or at least it should, select the proper localization directory, but it doesn't seem to do that which is why I came up with this solution.