# iOS Localizable.strings not being retrieved from BASE file

Tags: ios, ios7, localization, ios6.1, localizable.strings

I am having a problem getting localization on **iOS** to work the way I think it is suppose to, but this is my first foray into localization so maybe I am misunderstanding.

I have three **Localizable.strings** files:

**Base**

```
"TAB_TITLE_Camera" = "CAMERA";
```

**English**

```
"TAB_TITLE_Camera" = "Camera";
```

**Spanish**

```
"TAB_TITLE_Camera" = "Cámara";
```

---

```
NSLocalizedString(@"TAB_TITLE_Camera", nil)
```

---

**iOS 6.1**

On **Xcode 5** with a **4th generation iPod Touch** running **iOS 6.1**, **English** and **Spanish** seem to work, but if I change to **German** (or any other language without a localization file) it does not pull
from **Base Localizable.strings**, instead it pulls from the **English** file.

Why does it **NOT** pull from the **BASE** file?

Why **DOES** it pull from the **English** file?

---

**iOS 7.1**

Also, with a **5th generation iPod Touch** running **iOS 7.1**, when I change to **German** it seems to pull from the last selected language that has a localization file, either **English** or **Spanish**. Huh?!

Comment: Maybe I can use NSLocalizedStringFromTable to select the base file. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to determine whether or not I have a localization file for the currently selected language, and if not, I can pull from the **Base** localization file.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0] ofType:@"lproj"];
if (path == nil)
{
    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Base" ofType:@"lproj"];
}

NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"TAB_TITLE_Camera", @"Localizable", [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path], @"");
```

If the current language is:

**English** it returns **Camera**

**Spanish** it returns **Cámara**

Anything else that doesn't have a localization file returns **CAMERA**

Simple solution that does everything I need.

Works on both **iOS 6.1** and **iOS 7.1**.

Comment: what about just some key absent?